# Create new table with conditional sums in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

I have a table which includes multiple articles and their respective stock data. In this example, Article x has 3 entries because it has 3 different status in column 'Status'. I would like to create a new table with the columns 'Article', 'Stock' and 'Locked Stock'. Each article should only have one entry. 'Stock' should be the sum of all the article entries where 'Status' = null or blank. 'Locked stock' should be the sum of all the article entries where 'Status' = not null or not blank. Please see the attached picture with the current table above and the desired table below. It makes the explanation easier to understand.

I tried to write the SQL query, but it doesn't give me any result yet:

```
SELECT Article,
       Sum(Select Table.Stock FROM Table WHERE Table.Stock Is Null) AS Stock,
       Sum(SELECT Table.Stock FROM Table WHERE Table.Stock Is Not Null) AS [Locked Stock]
FROM Table
GROUP BY Article];
```

Appreciate your help!

Kind regards,
Marco

Comment: I think your approach is not ideal. Have a look at this: http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select article,
       sum(iif(status is null, stock, 0)) as stock,
       sum(iif(status not null, stock, 0)) as locked_stock
from table.stock
group by article;
```

To be honest, I don't know if you have more precise rules for determining locked stock.  This just checks if the value is `NULL` or not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple! I can work on more precise rules based on this.